# Closing Adobe Acrobat PRO DC after printing a pdf

Tags: python, pdf, printing, adobe

I am trying to create a script which prints every existing pdf with a specific printer driver. I work on Windows 10. I have thought the best way is to change the default driver at every file, such as:

```
import win32print
import win32api

# print testfile1.pdf with copy 1 of the driver
# which has default "print on both sides"

win32print.SetDefaultPrinter('iR 5880C EUR(1)')
win32api.ShellExecute(0,'print','testfile1.pdf','.',None,0)


# print testfile2.pdf with copy 2 of the driver
# which has default "print on 1 side"

win32print.SetDefaultPrinter('iR 5880C EUR(2)')
win32api.ShellExecute(0,'print','testfile2.pdf','.',None,0)
```

But when testfile1.pdf is printed, testfile2.pdf is printed with the same driver. The reason is that the files are printed using Adobe Acrobat PRO DC, which needs to be closed after printing testfile1.pdf to know that the default printer has changed. Is there a way to close Adobe Acrobat PRO DC after printing testfile1.pdf?

Answer (score 0):

My estimate would be to end the process associated with Adobe Acrobat Pro after each job. This could be handled through win32process.TerminateProcess. win32process.CreateProcess returns PyHANDLE parameter needed for TerminateProcess. Hope this is of some help.

Comment: Thank you very much, GLarose. Could you please give me an example about how to implement win32process.TerminateProcess in my code?

Comment: win32process.TerminateProcess takes 2 arguments (integers). Could you please tell me how I find out which integers shall I put?

Comment: this is a useful site for python win32 extension: http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32process.html